# What is the difference between referencing object.id vs object[:id] when you return a Model dataset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am in the Console environment busy reading all the rows from a table into a variable and I noticed that you can reference the results by specifing `my_object.id` OR `my_object[:id]`.

Can someone tell me if there is a specific reason for this? Is one of these 'methods' deprecated or what is the reason for this?

Here is a code snippit: (assuming all has been set)

```
my_object = MyModel.find(:all)
my_object[1].id #returns => 'my value'
my_object[1][:id] # also returns => 'my value'
```

Which of these methods are best practice? Or is it purely a notation preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
my_object[1].id
```

"id" is an instance method generated by rails in the MyModel class and it has its corresponding "id=" setter instance method (yes, it's a method)

in the other hand

```
my_object[1][:id] or my_object[1]["id"]
```

will access the @attributes hash directly:

```
    def read_attribute(attr_name)
      attr_name = attr_name.to_s
      if !(value = @attributes[attr_name]).nil?
      ......
    end
```

I'd like you to see this code

```
def [](attr_name)
   read_attribute(attr_name)
end

my_object[1][:id]
```

If you see the signature of the [] method maybe you'd think that you can call the method like this:

```
my_object[1][](:id)
```

but you can't do that because Ruby makes some trickery behind the scenes to make it appear just like if you were accessing a normal array (just like php, js, etc does it), don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of doing a `read_attribute`, which is protected, outside of the class. From the `ActiveRecord::Base` source code:

```
# Returns the value of the attribute identified by <tt>attr_name</tt> after it has been typecast (for example,
# "2004-12-12" in a data column is cast to a date object, like Date.new(2004, 12, 12)).
# (Alias for the protected read_attribute method).
def [](attr_name)
  read_attribute(attr_name)
end
```

`model.attribute` is the most common way of doing it. The `[]` method obviously works well if the name of the attribute is stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use model.attribute, it's both more standard and allows you flexibility if you need to override it:

```
u = User.first
u.identity_url
=> nil
class << u
  def identity_url
    read_attribute(:identity_url) || "undefined"
  end
end
=> nil
u.identity_url
=> "undefined"
u[:identity_url]
=> nil
```

Kind of a lame example, but you get the idea.